# tikz-cd arrows not aligned

Tags: tikz-cd

For some reason, the arrows in my tikz-cd diagram are not aligned. How do I get them to align?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzcd}[
        cells={nodes={draw=black, ellipse}}
]
        a \arrow[r] & b \arrow[r] & c \arrow[r] & d
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you using `ellipse` shape?

Comment: Some nodes can have a lot of text in them, and I don't want their height to be the same as their width... and I don't want the shape to be rectangular.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `anchor=center`. For the consistency in heights, I suggest using `minimum height`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[cells={nodes={draw=black,ellipse,anchor=center,minimum height=.75cm}}]
    a \arrow[r] & b \arrow[r] & c \arrow[r] & abcde
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's excellent, thank you! That not only aligned the arrows, it also made them look crisper too. :)